# Converting a PWM signal to reduced constant voltage or constant current output

Tags: pwm, detection

I'm dealing with an existing circuit that was originally designed to dim incandescent and halogen bulbs from 12V using low frequency PWM.  This PWM is visible to the naked eye when substituting a 12V LED circuit.  I want to detect when the 12v PWM signal is present and either convert it to a lower constant voltage or a limited constant current value.  Then when the PWM disappears from the line and becomes 100% duty cycle 12VDC, I want it to bypass the detection circuit so the full 12V reaches the LED.  Summary is dimming the LED when PWM is present, full power when PWM is not.  Total LED consumption is roughly 40W, so I was thinking of using a 5 pin relay to change between the 2 states.  The existing circuit is annoying because the PWM happens on the same line as full power mode (only a positive and negative wire). I still need to scope the PWM to find out the exact switching frequency.

Comment: This is a fairly easy circuit. Basically, you allow a resistor to charge up a capacitor. If the PWM signal goes to ground (or well below 12 V), you activate a BJT or FET that completely discharges the capacitor. So long as the frequency is present, even if the duty cycle is 90%, the capacitor will keep getting discharged and never reach the voltage it must reach for you to get a signal for 100%. Or you could frequency-double the PWM and discharge the capacitor on both edges. Either way, it's not complex. Can you design it?

Comment: _"The existing circuit is annoying because the PWM happens on the same line as full power mode (only a positive and negative wire)."_ - Do you have to use this to power the LEDs, or can you access the (or another) constant 12V power source when the PWM happens?

Comment: @jonk thanks for taking the time to share your insight.  I can't design it, but I can build it.  My brain didn't accept knowledge any deeper than a Sr Electronics Tech :).  I know what a BJT, FET resistor and cap (I'm assuming you had a large electrolytic in mind) is, but I wouldn't know the appropriate values or whether ancillary resistors, inductors, diodes and caps would be required.  I need to play around with the 12V LED to find an appropriate power level during PWM via constant voltage or constant current.  I'm guessing about 15W is going to be appropriate.

Comment: @jonk frequency doubling may need to be something more like frequency quadrupling.  It looks like the frequency of the PWM is around 15Hz, so I'd want to push it to at least 60Hz to be invisible to the eye.  Even higher would be better just in case.    I could probably scope the PWM and identify 100% duty cycle consumption vs the ideal reduced power level during PWM this weekend.  Either solution you mentioned sounds good.  My preference would be which ever circuit is more simple and a takes up less space.  I do have smart EEs around me, but they're always busy with work at our job.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott ideally I would insert the fix inline with the existing circuit for cleanliness and forgo a 3rd wire.

Comment: @Mitchell This is just a way to replace an incandescent with an LED indictator with the similar "dimming" and "full on" behavior? So that the LED is half-bright (to a human) when the PWM is 50%?

Comment: @jonk yes, that is correct thanks.

Comment: @Mitchell Then you'll need something more along the lines of a geometric (log/exp) LED current response because that's how humans see the world. Fortunately for incandescent bulbs, the black body radiation curve has a similar behavior with PWM. But LEDs ***do not***. So a special engineering consideration is required to make this work according to your expectations. Half the LED current does NOT look half as bright to a human. It might work to use a squaring function where the current is proportional to the relative duty cycle % squared. 50% would mean 1/4 current, etc.

Comment: @Mitchell This means a non-linear circuit. For me, it calls forth a Gilbert squarer using BJTs, or using diodes or mosfets in a part of their operation regime. A general class of things called "translinear" circuits. Anyway, I'm going to +1 your question because I'd actually like to see it performed well here. (I won't be interested in hacks that don't achieve the human perception goals, though.)

Comment: @jonk Thanks, I look forward to chatting with you further once I'm qualified with enough reputation.